# joinByArray field add to beginning of array in apostrophe-cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm hoping to get some help with what I think should be an easy request but can't seem to figure it out in apostrophe-cms. My client wants the joinByArray field to add articles to the beginning of the array instead of at the end is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file to look for would be `lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/public/js/array-modal.js`. Apostrophe isn't built to add items to the beginning of the array field items, but if you wanted to venture into customizing that behavior it would be by overriding that file.

Comment: if the file does not exists in  lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/public/js/array-modal.js would I just create it or is there an apos cli command or something?

Comment: Sorry, that's a file from Apostrophe core. You would need to override that in the project. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/2.0/lib/modules/apostrophe-schemas/public/js/array-modal.js There is information about doing that in the "Extending the pieces editor modal" page of the v2 docs. It's not a small task, though.